# Wine32 is not installing on Ubuntu Bionic Beaver (development branch)?

Tags: apt, package-management, wine

I am trying to install wine on my Ubuntu OS (Ubuntu Bionic Beaver (development branch)).

But when I try APT throws an error about unmet dependencies. When I install the dependency it still shows an error.

I have run

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

and

```
sudo apt install -f
```

this didn't fix the problem.

[image: wine 32:i386 depends on libwine:i386 but it is not going to be installed]

Comment: Umm... maybe because it's a "development version", not intended for daily use?

Comment: @pomsky That is not a helpful comment, and 18.04 is in final beta and scheduled to be released next week. This should not be closed at this point.

Comment: However, please do not post screenshots of text and instead copy/paste the text in an [edit] of your question.

Comment: As for the issue, there's likely a conflict or some related issue, preventing the install. you'll need to do `apt install wine32 libwine:i386` to see why it fails to install (and so on if more packages are at issue). At some point it will likely resolve and also ask to remove other packages, but you should then know why it was failing.

Comment: @dobey I also think general how-to questions about final beta should not be closed. In this case from the screenshot I presumed the problem is with the package manager or the sources (or perhaps broken installation), hence not a general question but a bug. But well, I've been wrong before, and may very well be once again. :)

Comment: @dobey It got closed eventually, I VTR'ed.

Comment: The general issue presented in the screenshot is common, and not expressly limited to 18.04. It's what happens when there are underlying package conflicts or such, when you ask apt to install a higher level package, and one must explicitly install more packages to discover what the issue is.

Comment: That is to say it is this is likely a duplicate of another question, as it's common. But the original comment from @pomsky which I replied to is a bit condescending and sardonic, which is what I primarily have issue with here.

Comment: @dobey To be completely honest it was a somewhat genuine reaction as I was inclined to the conclusion that it's a bug/broken-system but still had some doubt whether it is a general problem.